# Typescript: Define initial state for object using interface with dictionary of keys

Tags: typescript, dictionary, syntax, interface, initialization

I've defined my interface as follows:

```
export interface FullCache {
    // keys names are dynamic
    [cacheId: string]?: SingleCache;
}

export interface SingleCache {
    data: string;
}
```

so an example FullCache object could look like this:

```
{
    ca001:{data:'foo'},
    ca002:{data:'bar'}
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to define an intial state for FullCache because it uses a dictionary of keys. I tried simply defining an empty object:

```
export const fullCacheInitialState: FullCache = {

};
```

but webpack gives the error `error TS1131: Property or signature expected.`

Comment: `error TS1131: Property or signature expected.` is due to the optional `?` symbol. It isn't valid on key-value definition. Remove that and you can initialise your dictionary with your example object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as an [optional index signature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7118).  The question mark in the following is an error:

```
export interface FullCache {
    [cacheId: string]?: SingleCache; // error
}
```

Index signatures already act like optional properties in that no key is required.  So, you can change it to

```
export interface FullCache {
    [cacheId: string]: SingleCache; // okay
}
```

or, if you are trying to capture the fact that a `FullCache` object [might return `undefined`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778) when you access a missing property, you can define it like this:

```
export interface FullCache {
    [cacheId: string]: SingleCache | undefined; // okay
}
```

Either way should clear up your error.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!